# How to extract numpy array stored in tuple?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's consider very easy example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 1, 2])
print(np.where(a < -1))
(array([], dtype=int64),)
print(np.where(a < 2))
(array([0, 1]),)
```

I'm wondering if its possible to extract length of those arrays, i.e. I want to know that the first array is empty, and the second is not. Usually it can be easily done with `len` function, however now numpy array is stored in tuple. Do you know how it can be done?

Comment: `len(np.where(a < 2)[0])`?

Answer (score 2):

Just use this:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 1, 2])
x = np.where(a < 2)[0]
print(len(x))
```

Outputs `2`

Answer (score 1):

To find the number of values in the array satisfying the predicate, you can skip `np.where` and use `np.count_nonzero` instead:

```python3
a = np.array([0, 1, 2])
print(np.count_nonzero(a < -1))
>>> 0
print(np.count_nonzero(a < 2))
>>> 2
```

If you need to know whether there are any values in `a` that satisfy the predicate, but not how many there are, a cleaner way of doing so is with `np.any`:

```python3
a = np.array([0, 1, 2])
print(np.any(a < -1))
>>> False
print(np.any(a < 2))
>>> True
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.where` takes 3 arguments: `condition, x, y` where last two are arrays and are optional. When provided the funciton returns element from `x` for indices where `condition` is `True`, and `y` otherwise. When only `condition` is provided it acts like `np.asarray(condition).nonzero()` and returns a tuple, as in your case. For more details see *Note* at [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

Alternatively, because you need only length of sublist where `condition` is `True`, you can simply use `np.sum(condition)`:

```py
a = np.array([0, 1, 2])
print(np.sum(a < -1))
>>> 0
print(np.sum(a < 2))
>>> 2
```

Comment: he's using the single argument version of `np.where`